# Find unique name of device?

Tags: android, networking, bonjour, zeroconf

I'm developing an app that uses zeroconf (bonjour) to discover devices - so I need to give each android device some kind of name (not just a bunch of numbers and letters, but something meaningful like "Alex's Device"). In iOS it can be easily done - is this possible in android?

Comment: @inazaruk I don't believe is a dupe: using a 64-bit hex string or a mac address is not what I would call *something meaningful like "Alex's Device")*

Comment: just ask the user for a name via a field or preference.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's clearly the best solution, but it is always nice to give some user-friendly default value

Comment: @Aleadam: OK, now I think I understand the original question better.

Comment: @Aleadam, you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many accounts linked to the device. You can use the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to get them. For example, emails on google accounts:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);

Account[] ac = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");

for (Account account : ac) {
  Log.d ("Account", ac.name);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [android.os.Build.MODEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) or similar.

Comment: the account name isn't unique. i can have two devices linked to the same google account.

Comment: So you can have two iphones with the same user name. I am trying to give the answer that more closely targets the question.

Comment: that's not what he asked. "so I need to give each android device". EACH ... DEVICE, not EACH ... USER.

Comment: @farble what do you mean "that's not what he asked"? If the OP accepted the answer there must be a reason for it... I try to read the **context** of the question, not just the words.

Comment: let me try again, to quote the OP: "I need to give each android device some kind of name". notice that he said he needs to give "each device", not the user. account names are user names, and they are not per device as the OP requested. got it now?

Comment: @farble you forgot to quote *something meaningful like "Alex's Device"* . If the OP didn't accept the answer, I would be willing to evaluate your objection. But he did, thus I was correct. It is always more important here to answer with regards to **the OP's intention, rather than the literal wording**. If you have an issue with how the question is formulated, fell free to edit it. Let me know you did it and I'll approve the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application requires a device to have a network connection, you can try using the MAC address of the device, which should be globally unique. This can be obtained with the WifiInfo class:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = info.getMacAddress();
```

You'll also need to set the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the IMEI of the Android Phone , it's Unique  ,

you can Get it by using the method `getDeviceId()` of the Class `TelephonyManager`

**NOTE :** you will need to add a permission in your manifest : `READ_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: i said Android Phone , i did'nt say tablets, and i think that on tablets ,there is an Identifient , i didn't work or use it , just "i think " :)

Answer (score 0):

For detailed instructions on how to get a Unique Identifier for each Android device your application is installed from, see this official Android Developers Blog posting:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

It seems the best way is for you to generate one your self upon installation and subsequently read it when the application is re-launched.

I personally find this acceptable but not ideal. No one identifier provided by Android works in all instances as most are dependent on the phone's radio states (wifi on/off, cellular on/off, bluetooth on/off). The others like Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID must be implemented by the manufacturer and are not guaranteed to be unique.

The following is an example of writing data to an INSTALLATION file that would be stored along with any other data the application saves locally.

```
public class Installation {
    private static String sID = null;
    private static final String INSTALLATION = "INSTALLATION";

    public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
        if (sID == null) {  
            File installation = new File(context.getFilesDir(), INSTALLATION);
            try {
                if (!installation.exists())
                    writeInstallationFile(installation);
                sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return sID;
    }

    private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        f.readFully(bytes);
        f.close();
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation);
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        out.write(id.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }
}
```